# C++ Private variable of a class is a pointer. How do i have to write setter ? + enumeration

Tags: c++, pointers, enums, setter, getter

Hi everyboy :) I m pretty new on programming and especially on C++. 
This is why I am trying to test some beginners functions like getters and setters with private variable which are, in fact, pointers. I m doing this tests for an assignement and i have to use enumeration too.
I got 0 compilation error but my test program is crashing when i m trying to set my private pointer with an enum type.

Here is my class "Slot": header file : Slot.hpp

```
#ifndef SLOT_H
#define SLOT_H

enum Pawn{YELLOW, RED};

class Slot
{
public:
    Slot();
    ~Slot();
    Slot(const Slot& slot_to_copy) {color = new Pawn(*(slot_to_copy.color));}

    void setColor(Pawn);
    Pawn getColor();

private:
    Pawn *color; 
};

#endif
```

Here is my source file: Slot.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Slot.hpp"

using namespace std;

Slot::Slot() {color = NULL;}

Slot::~Slot() {}

void Slot::setColor(Pawn col)
{
    *color = col;
}

Pawn Slot::getColor()
{
    return *color;
}
```

And here is my main where I am testing the getter and the setter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Slot.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Slot test;
    test.setColor(YELLOW); // testing the setter
    Pawn coin = test.getColor(); // testing the getter
    if (coin == YELLOW)
        cout <<"SUCCESS"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is located on the setter function ... 
Thank you in advance for your help, i already took 3 hours by trying to fix my problem and I cannot work on my assignement without this working correctly :/
Sorry for my approximate English by the way.

PS: I HAVE TO use pointer for that, because it is asked by my teacher and consist in the difficulty (or at least a part of it) of our programming assignement.

Comment: Your color pointer isn't initialized to anything in the Slot constructor.

Comment: Do you really need a pointer ?

Comment: Thank you :) This is one big point actually. I modified my code and i still got the same problem (crashing during the execution). I edit my post so you can see how i modified my constructor. Thank you for your fast answer :)

Comment: @user3106096 if you assign pointer to NULL it wouldn't get things any better - to be able to assign something to place where pointer points to you have to allocate some memory to it using `new`

Comment: If you _must_ use a pointer, don't forget to `delete` the current value each time you re-assign it, and in your destructor!

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing the pointer in the default constructor. This means de-referencing it is undefined behaviour. You should make it point to something you can write to later:

```
Slot::Slot() : color(new Pawn()) { }
```

Note that having a class manage dynamically allocated resources means it has to do sensible things in its copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor. See [*the rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

The easiest solution in not to use a pointer at all:

```
....
private:
    Pawn color;
```

Comment: I have to use the pointer, it is asked by my teacher and this consist in the difficulty ( or at least a part of it ) of our assignement.

Comment: @user3106096 how bizarre - a pointer to a (private) enum is next to useless - it'll take at least twice the memory of the enum would by itself.

Comment: @user3106096 That is a pity. I hope the teacher has a good reason for this. Anyway, you need to make the pointer point to an object you can write to. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your default constructor `Slot()` doesn't allocate space for the `Pawn *color`, so it'll just point to some random location in memory. When you write to it you'll write to this random location.

You can set it like this:

```
Slot::Slot() : color(new Pawn)
{}
```

Here we're using the member initializer list to set `color` to allocated memory before the body of the constructor is executed. It's conceptually the same as saying:

```
Slot::Slot()
{
  color = new Pawn;
}
```

For integral types and pointers there's not much difference. However, if the member variables were class instances then the member variable initializer list is the only way to initialize classes that do not have a default constructor.

However, since `enum` is effectivly an int there's no point is using a pointer. Just declare it as:

```
Pawn color;
```

And get/set it like this:

```
void Slot::setColor(Pawn col)
{
    color = col;
}

Pawn Slot::getColor()
{
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Now it seems to be working as i would like it works ! 
Can you just explain me in a few details what this line is doing please ? 
    Slot::Slot() : color(new Pawn)
    {}
I do not understand the construction with color(new Pawn)

Comment: @user3106096 - I've added some more information to the answer.

Comment: Loving you :) Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Your `color` pointer is being assigned to something only in copy constructor, while in your `main` you are creating `Slot` using default constructor, that's why pointer stays uninitialized and behaviour of functions like `setColor` is undefined.